# How can I save ONLY when I add a new record

Tags: excel

Save ONLY when adding new record

I have only tried to add 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
It did not work.  I still get the Save message even if I am only querying the database

There are two parts of the script.  The first one just allows me to view the word associated with the code.  The second part allows me to create a new word and assigns the next code number (sequential).  There is not much code so I am showing both modules here.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="wood3481"
    ' Range("c3:g10000").Locked = True
    Dim PW As Range
    If Target.Address <> "$C$3" Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set PW = Sheet1.Columns(6).Find(Target)
    If Not PW Is Nothing Then
        [D3] = PW.Offset(, 1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
    '  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="wood3481"
    Range("C3").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ' All cells are Locked except for C3, D3 and  D4 which is  required  to change them with script
    ' Additionaly, the data storage range (g2:f10000) is Locked to allow the sript to run
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    '  This script records the new password
    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
    Dim id
    Dim idnew
    Dim pswd
    '  Unprotect the spreadsheet to allow modification
    '        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="vfgtrfd"
    pswd = Application.InputBox("Enter New Password")
    ' Find the end of the password codes column
    Range("f1").End(xlDown).Select
    ' Remember last code assigned
    id = ActiveCell.Value
    ' Move down 1 cell which is where new code will be stored
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ' Write new code to database
    ActiveCell.Value = id + 1
    idnew = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = pswd
    MsgBox ("Here is your new password ID: " & idnew)
    Range("c4").Value = idnew
    '        Range("c4").Locked = True
    '  Protect the spreadsheet before returning teh unlocked cell
    '        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="vfgrfdr"
    ' Move cursor back to Input cell
    Range("c3").Select

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.  I went for SIMPLE. I added a ActiveWorkbook.Save command so now I SAVE no matter what I am doing.  It is easy, quick and simple.  Problem solved.